# A man notices that has wife has tentacles coming out of her body that lead down to the sea

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

All I remember is that there's a scene where a man's wife(?) walks into the room and then he notices that she has tentacles coming out of her that lead all throughout the house(?) to the sea(?)

It may have been set in a lighthouse.

Comment: I sincerely doubt that that's all you remember. Have a look at the checklists here and start editing in any info you can add; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: For example, when did you see it? Was it in black and white or colour? Was it horror for kids or adults? Who played the man? Who played the wife? What were their names? How did he react to the tentacles?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pVyfcq20Vqo

Comment: Dagon? https://birthmoviesdeath.com/2015/02/05/fuck-dagon.-yes